# unit testing a control with database access

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

I am into development for a while and now my manager is asking me to do unit testing. The code has database connections, loading dropdowns, web services etc. I have a method like the below,

```
private void Load()
    {
        ddl.DataTextField = "a";
        dd.DataValueField = "b";
        ddl.DataSource = Utility.Getval(ddlCorp.SelectedItem.Text);
        ddl.DataBind();

        ddl.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

And my test method looks like below,

```
  public class UnitTest1
   {
      [TestMethod]
       public void TestMethod1()
       {
          var simpleTabControl = new SimpleTabControl();
          PrivateObject o = new PrivateObject(typeof(SimpleTabControl));
          b bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(o.Invoke("Load"));
      }
```

How to check selected value of dropdown and also check if its correctly binded. Is it possible to unit test this? When I debug I get null exception in ddl.

Comment: Unit testing is not something you can do after the fact. *Unit* testing means you need to program a *unit* first, a small, self contained module. If your control accesses the database, it's not a unit, it's a piece of code with external dependencies. Remove those first, maybe using mock objects and dependency injections. Then unit test your code using it's public interface. Do not test privates. You are not supposed to know them from the outside.

Comment: @nvoigt are you sure? I know where you're coming from but your first sentence that is kind of wrong anyway. Unit testing is simply unit testing, you are free to unit-test before, during and after development. I'm pretty sure that what you refer to is Test Driven Development (TDD) as a common and recommended practice

Comment: @Leo You can absolutely do unit testing after development. *If* you are magically gifted and developed *units* despite not knowing you will need them. I have seen to much code that worked and was not unit-testable simply because people never thought about it. How do you unit test something that opens a database connection in a control? You cannot. That requires *really* heavy lifting. If he had started with dependency injection, it would be a breeze to exchange his datasource for a mock.

Comment: Ok. how do I remove dependency and what should I mock here. Any article will be helpful. am new to unit testing and I need bit of guidance to proceed with it

Comment: You will need to remove or replace anything that influences parts outside of your unit test. You should be able to run the unit test without *any* dependencies. A common pattern is using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to do this. You should really get a good book or tutorial on unit testing, explaining it is way beyond this Q&A format here.

Comment: @nvoigt ok, this is getting confusing. I don't remember mentioning anything about unit testing a whole user control. I'm just highlighting the difference between unit testing and TDD because people use the terms indistinctively all the time. And, AFAIK, unit testing does not define when you can unit test...and you definitely don't need to be a guru or a wizard to write a unit test of something that has already been developed

Comment: @Leo Then you know more than me. How would you test this already developed control that has database connections baked in? Because I can not. Not without refactoring it. And I'm not talking about TDD at all. I hate it. I'm just talking about the fact that unit testing a component that was developed without thinking about what a *component* is will have slim chances. Because you cannot *unit test* something that's not even a *unit*. Like this control in this post. It's not a unit, it has external dependencies that cannot be mocked.

Comment: @nvoigt lol...this is getting funny, especially because I have not disagreed with any of what you said...except the first sentence in your first comment. But you keep banging on about unit testing a user control...so, I'll just leave it there

Comment: @nvoigt unit-testing opening Db Connections can be probably done using Microsoft Fakes Shims (although the resulting frankenstein of a test will not improve the developer's life nor the resulting product)

Comment: @Aswini The code demonstrates that the original developer is not familiar with the IoC pattern nor DRY principle which combined are logical (if not philosophical) cornerstones of modern c# unit-testing. Read up on dependency injection, SOLID principles of OOP and refactor. Then you will be able to unit-test.